# Using ROS to run a TP program on Fanuc

Tags: ros, ros-kinetic, fanuc

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello all,

I have a Fanuc LR Mate 200 iC that works with ROS (MoveIt and everything else works). I have a pneumatic schunk end effector attached to the arm and I would like to be able to actuate it using ROS. One easy way to do so could be using a two TP programs one for opening the gripper and the other for closing it and running these programs with a command within ROS.

Is this possible or is it a better way to accomplish this (in a short amount of time)?

I am running ROS Kinetic on Ubuntu 16.04, if that matters.

Thanks.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/321698/using-ros-to-run-a-tp-program-on-fanuc/) by [ccetin](https://answers.ros.org/users/41002/ccetin/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2019-04-23

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-04-23**:
Which driver are you using?

**Comment by [ccetin](https://answers.ros.org/users/41002/ccetin/) on 2019-04-23**:
gvdhoorn,

Thanks for the prompt reply and all the work you put into Fanuc packages. I am using the indigo-devel branch of the fanuc_driver. The controller is R30i and the TP version is v7.70P/31.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> I am using the indigo-devel branch of the fanuc_driver.

First: please use [fanuc_driver_exp](https://github.com/gavanderhoorn/fanuc_driver_exp) instead of `fanuc_driver` (it's a drop-in replacement for the controller side of `fanuc_driver`).

As to executing TP programs: that is not something that `fanuc_driver_exp` currently supports (nor `fanuc_driver`). You could either extend `fanuc_driver_exp` with such functionality (which should not be terribly difficult, but would be some work in Karel), or perhaps -- if your programs would really just be (re)setting digital or analog IOs -- just control the IOs directly.

For that you could use either a fieldbus integrated with ROS (there are some packages for that, Ethernet/IP, modbus or profinet fi) but you would need fieldbus support on your Fanuc controller (or a PLC) or you could see whether [gavanderhoorn/fanuc_ros_cgio_py](https://github.com/gavanderhoorn/fanuc_ros_cgio_py) is sufficiently performant. It is **not** meant for production use, but for the occasional ON/OFF in a research/hobby setting it might be enough.

There is no ROS node, but the Python library should be easy enough to wrap in a simple node with two services that toggle your IOs.

---

Edit:

> I will update the post if I get the time to try either of the methods. I was hoping there would be a hacky/quick fix type of way of doing this but I guess not.

Not sure whether this would be any faster (as it would still require some programming), but you could potentially use the RSR or PNS system (digital IOs triggering execution of programs) in combination with your short programs to open/close the gripper.

Another alternative: use a PLC with some "easier" interface than digital IOs to control the IO of the gripper.

> I saw gavanderhoorn/fanuc_ros_cgio_py before I posted but I don't think I can implement this with the time constraint I have

Literally the *only* thing missing would be a [Python Service Server](http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/WritingServiceClient%28python%29#rospy_tutorials.2BAC8-Tutorials.2BAC8-WritingServiceClient.Writing_a_Service_Node) that exposes two services: `open` and `close`.

In `open`, it calls `robot.write_dout(..)` with as argument the DOUT that opens your gripper, and in `close` it calls `robot.write_dout(..)` with as argument the DOUT that closes your gripper.

Provided your gripper actually works that way, that should be 30 mins work, max.

If your gripper is controlled using `ROUT` (ie: robot out), you could even check [the example](https://github.com/gavanderhoorn/fanuc_ros_cgio_py/blob/master/examples/toggle_rdout1.py).

---

Edit 2: just came across [ABC-iRobotics/fanuc-webcontrol](https://github.com/ABC-iRobotics/fanuc-webcontrol), which contains a program called [webstart](https://github.com/ABC-iRobotics/fanuc-webcontrol/blob/f7f2c671ee51dd17ca7431df8e167cdc8a2b1717/karel/webstart.kl) which can apparently be used to start TP programs by just visiting a URL. Similar to the idea in `gavanderhoorn/fanuc_ros_cgio`, but one step closer to what you asked for (ie: starting programs).

Would still need wrapping in a ROS node, but that would probably be even easier than with `gavanderhoorn/fanuc_ros_cgio_py`.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2019-04-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-04-23**:
There could of course be other options / approaches, but this is what I could recommend as a quick fix.

**Comment by [ccetin](https://answers.ros.org/users/41002/ccetin/) on 2019-04-23**:
I saw gavanderhoorn/fanuc_ros_cgio_py before I posted but I don't think I can implement this with the time constraint I have and I have no experience with Karel for the first suggestion you had. I will update the post if I get the time to try either of the methods.  I was hoping there would be a hacky/quick fix type of way of doing this but I guess not.

Thanks a lot for the help!

Edit: I have the necessary packages for the fanuc_ros_cgio_py, I will give that a shot. Thanks again gvdhoorn.

**Comment by [ccetin](https://answers.ros.org/users/41002/ccetin/) on 2019-04-25**:
The method you suggested in the last edit seems to be working. I can initiate TP programs from the browser. I will write a ROS wrapper to include it in my code.

Thanks a lot!

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-04-26**:
Just for my understanding: the two "small TP programs" you mention, do they (un)set digital IOs?

**Comment by [ccetin](https://answers.ros.org/users/41002/ccetin/) on 2019-04-26**:
I had other TP programs that might have been useful to run but yes essentially that was the idea. But I think implementing `gavanderhoorn/fanuc_ros_cgio` for that makes much more sense, so I will do that as well.

edit: implemented `gavanderhoorn/fanuc_ros_cgio` works as intended.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-04-30**:\

> edit: implemented `gavanderhoorn/fanuc_ros_cgio` works as intended.

would be awesome if you could make your node available. That would benefit future users tremendously.

**Comment by [ccetin](https://answers.ros.org/users/41002/ccetin/) on 2019-05-02**:
I will make it available once I clean the code up a bit.

On a side note, I ran into some issues trying to run another TP program while ROS is running. It is not letting me run another program with movement in it with the alert "already locked by other task". Any idea on how to resolve this @gvdhoorn?

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-05-03**:
It's considered bad form to post follow-up questions under an answer to an answered question. It's better to post a new question.

But in short: the driver commands motion, so it locks motion groups. You cannot start another program that commands motion while the driver is running (or at least: the trajectory relaying part).